# What is the best and fastest way to clean-up traces of JHipster?

Tags: jhipster

When you build with a code generator, sometimes you would like to remove traces, if you will, of anything in the source that clearly shows that you have used a generator to bootstrap your project.
This is something that possibly can be done manually and by refactoring, with some efforts and knowledge of the code and its structure.
Of course, this what you would want to do when your code is stable and you know that you won't be using the generator again.

The Question:
What is the best and fastest way to clean-up traces of JHipster and there scripts out there to do this?

Comment: I compare what I am asking here, with Removing Spring Roo from a project.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason why you would want to remove traces of jhipster? If I saw that someone's code used the jhipster generator, I'd be have more confidence in it than if they had rolled it themselves--knowing that jhipster is built using the collective brains of the development community. I don't think there are any tools that remove traces of jhipster

Comment: It comes handy for creating an archetype after making your own changes to the generated project.